# Как сделать, чтобы цикл больше не повторялся до перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, массивы, таблицы

У меня есть двумерный массив, я вывожу его в таблицу через кнопку, но если постоянно жмакать кнопку, то будет создаваться каждый раз новый массив и добавляться на страницу в виде новой таблицы.. Как итог: бардак на страничке.. Есть ли какой - то способ, который будет каждый раз менять эту таблицу, Но не создавать новую?

```js
function pyatoe() 
{
    let table = document.createElement("TABLE")
let tableBody = document.createElement("TBODY")
table.appendChild(tableBody)
 var ma=10;
var mi=-10;
var dvmas = [
[Math.floor(Math.random()*(ma-mi)), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi)],
[Math.floor(Math.random()*(ma-mi)), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi)],
[Math.floor(Math.random()*(ma-mi)), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi)],
[Math.floor(Math.random()*(ma-mi)), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi), Math.floor(Math.random()*ma-mi)]
];
for (let i = 0; i < dvmas.length; i++) 
    {   
  let tr = document.createElement("TR")
  tableBody.appendChild(tr); 
            {
    for (let j = 0; j < dvmas[i].length; j++) 
    {
      let td = document.createElement("TD")
      td.innerHTML = dvmas[i][j];
      tr.appendChild(td)
    }
            }
    }
document.body.appendChild(table)
[...table.children].forEach(children => children.remove());
console.log(dvmas)
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<label id="bl">Массив MxN: </label>
 <button onclick="pyatoe()">Создать</button>
 <div id="masdv">Массив:
```

Comment: `[...table.children].forEach(children => children.remove())` отчистит таблицу и её можно будет наполнять заного

Comment: код теперь вообще не работает(

Comment: Если не нужно отчищать таблицу, вы можете использовать ваш код, только вместо `tableBody = document.createElement("TBODY");` пишите `tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody');`, и тогда таблица будет продолжать наполняться без очистки.

Comment: вам проще будет опубликовать рабочий или нерабочий код сниппетом. При редактировании вопроса нажмите `Ctrl+M`. Создайте кнопку и все, что она делает. А то не до конца понятно что именно вы хотите добиться и что не работает.

Comment: сделала сниппет..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я добавил в верстку пустую таблицу, что бы её не создавать в Javascript.

Код

```
 let tableBody = document.querySelector('.mytable tbody');
```

ищет эту таблицу вместо создания.

Еще я заменил `Math.floor()` на `~~`, так выглядит нагляднее.

```js
function pyatoe() 
{
    let tableBody = document.querySelector('.mytable tbody');
    [...tableBody.children].forEach(children => children.remove());
 var ma=10;
var mi=-10;
var dvmas = [
[~~(Math.random()*(ma-mi)), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi)],
[~~(Math.random()*(ma-mi)), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi)],
[~~(Math.random()*(ma-mi)), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi)],
[~~(Math.random()*(ma-mi)), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi), ~~(Math.random()*ma-mi)]
];
for (let i = 0; i < dvmas.length; i++) 
    {   
  let tr = document.createElement("TR")
  tableBody.appendChild(tr); 
            {
    for (let j = 0; j < dvmas[i].length; j++) 
    {
      let td = document.createElement("TD")
      td.innerHTML = dvmas[i][j];
      tr.appendChild(td)
    }
            }
    }
   // console.log(dvmas)
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<label id="bl">Массив MxN: </label>
 <button onclick="pyatoe()">Создать</button>
 <div id="masdv">Массив:</div>
 <table class="mytable">
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: аа....  я тупица х) спасибо Вам большое!!! безумно выручили

Comment: @CindyLongstickluv не стоит быть столь категоричной. Процесс получения опыта в программировании лежит через совершение сотен тысяч ошибок и неудачных решений. Каждая совершенная ошибка в момент осознания навсегда меняет ваше мышление. Именно ошибки и неудачные решения расширяют границы вашего сознания. А чтобы не совершать этих ошибок - надо просто ничего не делать! :-)